# Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError - by click_link in rails 3.2.12 integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

Here is a piece of code in rails integration test with capybara:

```
it "should work with links on index page" do
      visit customers_path
      save_and_open_page
      click_link 'Edit'
end
```

The html page displayed is:

[image]

There is a Edit link in the page. However click_link 'Edit' still throws out the error:

```
 1) TestPaths GET /customerx_test_paths should work with links on index page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mclick_link 'Edit'←[0m
     ←[31mCapybara::InfiniteRedirectError:←[0m
       ←[31mredirected more than 5 times, check for infinite redirects.←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/features/customerx/customerx_test_paths_spec.rb:130:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

The integration test for edit customer passes. But every click_link in the test gives us the error. What could be wrong with the code? Thanks.

Comment: What happen if you click on the edit link with your browser? Does it works correctly?

Comment: The html page was generated by capabara and the link is not click-able.